# Why does voting in the election not ask me to sign up or log in?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, moderator-election

When I upvote or downvote the answer in Stack Overflow it asks me to Sign in or Sign up like this:

[image: popup appearing after voting while being logged out]

But it does not show me the same popup when voting in the [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1).

Is that by design or a bug?

**Update:**

Just noted this point in console, thanks [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene)

1. When I upvote a question/answer, I don't get any error.
2. But when I upvote on the election page, I am getting this error:

[image: JS error in console]

Comment: Looks like a bug as in `StackExchange.vote.up($(this))` vote is undefined on the election page. On the other hand I don't think the votes there should go into the anonymous postfeedback but that needs SE staff to confirm.

Comment: To be honest, users who can't vote in elections shouldn't arrive the election page to begin with, but still... they can click something somewhere to reach it, and there is indeed a JS bug which is ugly.

Comment: Indeed it looks like a bug!! But the good thing is votes are not captured which is how it should actually work. But I believe a pop up like above would improve the user experience.

Comment: Election meddling. How 2018.

Comment: Stack Analytica.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a signup call on these wouldn't be very helpful since you need 150+ rep to actually be able to vote. But, starting with the next build, attempting to upvote and downvote a nomination during the primary election phase will show a message rather than do nothing:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Because [when you "just use jQuery"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364913/why-stackoverflow-uses-jquery)  your code often depends in fragile ways on the DOM structure, instead of having clean access to an client view model. It's easier to miss an edge case.

Elections are very edgy cases.

Comment: It seems like the bug isn't actually related to the use of jQuery but I'm clinging to my joke.

Comment: so... there's a possibility that simply adding more jquery might fix it?