# Why Stack Overflow use jQuery?

Tags: discussion

I see by typing `$().jquery` into the browser console that Stack Overflow is using jQuery

Wouldn't using a framework like Vue or React be better and improve overall site performance?

If not, why?

Comment: If anything... we need [*moar jquery!*...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)

Comment: They do use modern stuff somewheres, but the core code base is big and it's probably not worth the effort for the team to spend the time updating things, when they're all already familiar with what they have, and maybe less familiar with modern front-end choices. Maybe it'd be a nice stretch goal for after things calm down.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Thats a great answer!

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: By the time they finish (not start) there will be half a dozen new frameworks just waiting to be adopted by the site.

Comment: 4 new javascript frameworks were released and abandoned since this question was first posted.

Comment: @Bolt: I don't think that's really true. We're past the insane churn of ~2010. When new frameworks are coming out, they're a lot closer to each other than they are to the old world. (Edit: okay, maybe by the time they finish, cause that's potebtially open-ended. ;)

Comment: Actually, jQuery is still faster. React, Angular, Vue as all very slow. If Stackoverflow were to update their client code to be faster they would remove jQuery and go to 100% vanillaJS, which of course is the fastest.

You can easily see the affect the fast food frameworks have if you open up your dev tools and do a perf audit, or run a page through Web page test. If you see a giant yellow slug (where the CPU is processing JavaScript) that is bad. You want that to be as little as possible.
FWIW I could probably build the JS required for a site like SO in 2-3000 lines of JavaScript

Answer (score 29):

Because Stack Overflow development began in 2007 when jQuery had just become the in thing (whether that was the *reason* they chose jQuery is a separate discussion). Vue.js and React didn't exist until more than half a decade later.

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Relevant: [All the Cool Kids Use Ruby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GpOfwbFRcs) (from the same guy who brought you [MongoDB is Web Scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs))

Comment: Well, 11 years has passed. I think that a use of a modern js framework would do great things to the site.dont you thinks so?

Comment: @GabMic: What "great things", besides a slight improvement in performance? Do you understand the scope of migrating a complex and mature site to a completely different architecture?

Comment: Slight improvements in s site such big as SOF, is actually a great deal. I haven't done any benchmarks but a more data-centric  approach to it would mean more flexibility, faster load times etc

Comment: "_I haven't done any benchmarks_" Then what do you think there is to improve, exactly?

Comment: @GabMic: How much development time would you estimate it would take to rebuild the complete SE network to work with, say, react?

Comment: That's easy. 6 to 8 weeks. (Previously I was feeling optimistic)

Comment: I thought it was 6 to 8?

Comment: @GabMic: "I haven't done any benchmarks" Oh, so you're one of *those* people...

Comment: @Cerbrus About 1 year.

Comment: @pat A typical jQuery mess is more error prone and harder to maintain than using a modern choice. There are reasons not to make the change, but it's not like people are just adopting these because they're hip -- we have actually made progress as an industry in the past ten years! :P

Comment: @GabMic: Based on what?

Comment: IMO The site is fast and responsive. JQuery or not.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier then why did I just wait THIRTY SIX whole minutes for an answer to my problem? clearly speed is an issue...

Comment: @rlemon: You didn't ask a question that was easy to FGITW.

Comment: Based on the fact that netflix moved to react in "no time" because they have a large team, but SOF is tiny compared to netflix. based on that i can say that the transfer would be around 1 year.

Comment: @GabMic About "a year" or a _person year_ or what? Of what developer team composition? What experience? What release cadence? Does this assume current feature development is completely halted, or that it's duplicated once in jQuery (for immediate release) and once in Vue, for later? There are _so_ many moving parts in a big, mature piece of software that you simply can't do this.

Comment: @rlemon If you mean It was loading for 36 minutes, that never happened to me.

Comment: Are we re-enacting [podcast nr 5](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/05/14/podcast-5/)?

Comment: @GabMic just curious, have you touched legacy code before?

Comment: Yes. i have. @AndrewT.

Comment: With a long stick I hope ... in case it bites ...

Comment: @GabMic So you can't think of anything that the SO team could do with *a year* of development time that would add more value than perhaps shaving a few milliseconds off of page rendering times?

Comment: Exactly. Thats why i asked it. SOF should never be in a state of legacy code. no matter how well the team knows it.

Comment: By the way, it's SO, not SOF.

Comment: After your first commit you have legacy code

Comment: no legacy code? How can such a utopia exist? This is just.... never true... Unless you count "no code".

Comment: @Patrice I guess they could switch to a *configuration* only platform. Sharepoint, Dynamics or SAP if you need something beefier...

Comment: @rene migrating from a codebase to such a platform is a 6 to 8 weeks endeavor.... right?

Comment: @Patrice that is what  pre-sales told me ...

Comment: @GabMic jQuery's latest release was 55 days ago. Is that not modern?

Comment: @msanford [Y'all just upvoted a bug that's nicely representative of why jQuery is old and busted, and we might want the new hotness instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364922/1114).

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: Do you regret not converting the site (or getting the chance to) before you left?

Comment: @JeremyBanks I upvoted a bug. I think fixing it by rewriting the entire platform in `!jQuery` is hasty as a solution especially, as you point out, this bug is edge-casey (though not of trivial importance). That said, I haven't used jQuery in yonks because I really don't like it, and it doesn't serve any function for me. But I'm also not rewriting old, working software in something new because it's prohibitive.

Comment: @JeremyBanks The point is about building *a business case* to convert the platform, not a technical case. Believe me, starting my career in open source, it was incredibly difficult for me to wrap my head around the business aspect, but it's ultimately the driving factor.